# Formatting date from a DatePicker

Tags: android

I know I can get the date from a datepicker using the following methods:

- datepicker1.getDayOfMonth()
- datepicker2.getMonth()
- datepicker3.getYear()

I am also getting the time from a timepicker using the following methods:

- timepicker1.getCurrentHour()
- timepicker2.getCurrentMinute()

I need to format this data into "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" format to place it into an sqlite database as a DATETIME variable. Is there a method which can handle this?

I think I will have to build it manually like so:

```
if(month < 10){
    month = "0" + month;
}
if(day < 10){
    day  = "0" + day ;
}
```

The problem was that the months and days were single digit.

Comment: what you have tried ? Any code reference ?

Comment: `time=""+data.getExtras().getString("dateyear")+"-"+ data.getExtras().getString("datemonth")+"-"+data.getExtras().getString("dateday") + " " +data.getExtras().getString("timehour") + " : "+data.getExtras().getString("timeminute")  + ":00";`
I am trying to insert this into the database in a DATETIME field. I am wondering is there an easier way to get this yyyy-MM-dd and HH:mm:ss separately from the pickers and concatenate it then simply place it in the database

Comment: USe string builder and concatenate the string and pass it to SimpledateFormat with your required format

Comment: how? can you show me some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

Date ModifiedDate  = outputFormat.parse(strdate);
```

Comment: pass that to your modified date

Comment: I don't need a date object, i need the string? So i convert the date into a string?

Comment: Sorry wasn't really sure. Okie this one worked perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simple as below:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
dateFormat.parse(yourDateHere);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get Current Date by this following and save it to the string

```
String mydate = java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

now pass this string to the Simpledateformat class and define your desired Format like following

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(mydate);
```

Comment: Okay, so I tried what you said and executed this 
`time=""+data.getExtras().getString("dateyear")+"-"+ data.getExtras().getString("datemonth")+"-"+data.getExtras().getString("dateday") + " " +data.getExtras().getString("timehour") + " : "+data.getExtras().getString("timeminute")  + ":00";
          
          SimpleDateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
          String enddate= dateformat.format(time);`

Comment: except it gave this error:  
_03-05 14:43:24.972: E/AndroidRuntime(9227): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=1, data=Intent { cmp=com.example.shoppinglist/.AddItemActivity (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.shoppinglist/com.example.shoppinglist.AddItemActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
03-05 14:43:24.972: E/AndroidRuntime(9227):  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3319)_
@Usman Kurd